# translate propertyPath in ConstraintViolationList

Tags: symfony, localization, api-platform.com

I'm using API Platform v3

When I `POST` with an invalid body I get a `422` response with this json

```
{
    "@context": "/contexts/ConstraintViolationList",
    "@type": "ConstraintViolationList",
    "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
    "hydra:description": "phones[0].number: This value should not be blank.",
    "violations": [
        {
            "propertyPath": "phones[0].number",
            "message": "This value should not be blank.",
            "code": "c1051bb4-d103-4f74-8988-acbcafc7fdc3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I succesfully implemented a translation service, so if I pass `Accept-Language` with a locale (`es`), then I get this json

```
{
    "@context": "/contexts/ConstraintViolationList",
    "@type": "ConstraintViolationList",
    "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
    "hydra:description": "phones[0].number: Este valor no debería estar vacío.",
    "violations": [
        {
            "propertyPath": "phones[0].number",
            "message": "Este valor no debería estar vacío.",
            "code": "c1051bb4-d103-4f74-8988-acbcafc7fdc3"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I'm not getting the `propertyPath` translated.

I would like `phones[0].number` to be `teléfonos[0].número` or `ńumero de telefono`.

Base on other entries in `translations/validators.es.yaml` (*), I've tried:

```
'phones[0].number': 'Número de teléfono'
'phones[{{ index }}].number': 'Número de teléfono'
'phones': 'teléfonos'
'phone': 'teléfono'
'number': número'
```

*: that file was generated via `php bin/console translation:extract es --force --format=yaml`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it with a `ConstraintViolationListener`

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use ApiPlatform\Symfony\Validator\Exception\ValidationException;

class ConstraintViolationListener
{
    private $translator;

    public function __construct($translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event): void
    {
        $exception = $event->getThrowable();

        if(!$exception instanceof ValidationException)
        {
            return;
        }

        $locale = $event->getRequest()->getLocale();

        $violations = $exception->getConstraintViolationList();

        $translatedViolations = [];

        foreach($violations as $violation)
        {
            $translatedPropertyPath = $this->translator->trans($violation->getPropertyPath(), [], "validators", $locale);

            $translatedMessage = $this->translator->trans($violation->getMessage(), $violation->getParameters(), "validators", $locale);

            $translatedViolations[] = [
                "propertyPath" => $translatedPropertyPath,
                "message" => $translatedMessage,
                "code" => $violation->getCode(),
            ];
        }

        $response = new JsonResponse();

        $response->setData([
            "@context" => "/contexts/ConstraintViolationList",
            "@type" => "ConstraintViolationList",
            "hydra:title" => $this->translator->trans("An error occurred", $violation->getParameters(), "validators", $locale),
            "hydra:description" => "",
            "violations" => $translatedViolations,
        ]);

        $response->setStatusCode(JsonResponse::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);

        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

And this entry in `validators.es.yaml`

```
'phones[0].number': 'Teléfono'
```